# pyparsing about Word and CaselessKeyword

Tags: python, pyparsing

I am new to pyparsing, I tried to use it to parse a DSL defined document. however, when I read the book from OReilly , I got a question about Word using.

```
from pyparsing import *

identifier = Word(alphas, alphanums + "_")

r1 = identifier.parseString("a____3")
print r1

(here pass)

identifier2 = CaselessKeyword(alphas, alphanums + "_")

r2 = identifier2.parseString("a____3")
print r2
```

(failed, pyparsing.ParseException: Expected "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" (at char 0), (line:1, col:1))
My questions:

The difference between Word and CaselessKeyword, I read the API said , [the API](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/pyparsing/web/class-CaselessKeyword.html), but it turns out 2nd match failed, why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- A `Word` is a `Token` for matching words composed of allowed
  character sets.
- A `Keyword` is a `Token`  which must *exactly* match a specified
  string *and* be immediately followed by a non-keyword character. So
  `Keyword(alphas, alphanums + "_")` must exactly match the string
  `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"` and be
  followed by something not in
  `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ_"`.
- A `CaselessKeyword` is the same as `Keyword` except that matches are
  case-insensitive.

`Word(alphas, alphanums + "_")` already matches caselessly since `alphas` includes both upper and lower case characters.

Comment: Thanks! so Word(alphas, alphanums + '\_') is actually same to Word( alphanums + '\_' ), right ?  The result shows that they are same, but I am not sure if they are same at low level.

Comment: It helps to read the docstrings. For example, `help(World)` shows the call signature is `Word(initChars, bodyChars, ...)` and `initChars` defines the character set for the initial character in a matching word, while `bodyChars` defines the character set for all the characters in the body. So `Word(alphas, ...)` must start with a character in `alphas`, while `Word(alphanums+'_')` can start with any character in `alphanums+'_'`.

Comment: thanks very much, at first, I thought [alphas, alphanums + '_'] means [alphas] OR [alphas + "_"], which seems wrong.  Thanks a lot !

Comment: Think of Keyword as a special form of Literal that will only match whole words. Literal('if') will match the first two characters of "ifonly", but Keyword('if') will not. Then CaselessLiteral and CaselessKeyword will match regardless of upper/lower case.